# Lubridate create interval operator %--% throws "'origin' must be supplied" error on NA

Tags: r, na, lubridate

The Lubridate `%--%` interval operator throws an error for certain configurations of NA and not-NA. In particular, why does the fourth call to `%--%` below return an error? Is this a bug?

```
> library(lubridate)

> c(ymd("1980-10-14"), ymd("1980-10-14")) %--% c(ymd("1981-10-14"), ymd("1982-10-14"))
[1] 1980-10-14 10:00:00 AEST--1981-10-14 10:00:00 AEST
[2] 1980-10-14 10:00:00 AEST--1982-10-14 10:00:00 AEST

> c(ymd("1980-10-14"), NA) %--% c(ymd("1981-10-14"), ymd("1982-10-14"))
[1] 1980-10-14 10:00:00 AEST--1981-10-14 10:00:00 AEST
[2] NA--NA                                           

> c(NA, NA) %--% c(ymd("1980-10-14"), ymd("1982-10-14"))
[1] NA--NA NA--NA

> c(NA, ymd("1980-10-14")) %--% c(ymd("1981-10-14"), ymd("1982-10-14"))
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(start) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

Note that

```
> NA %--% ymd("1981-10-14")
[1] NA--NA

> ymd("1981-10-14") %--% NA
[1] 1981-10-14 UTC--NA
```

Answer (score 2):

The anomaly is occurring in the fourth example because the `c` function returns a numeric class vector when the first argument is NA. On the other hand, it returns a POSIXct object when the first argument is a valid call to `ymd:

```
library(lubridate)
  c(NA, ymd("1980-10-14"))
#[1]        NA 340329600

 class( c(NA, ymd("1980-10-14")) )
#[1] "numeric"
 library(lubridate)
  class( c( ymd("1980-10-14"))  )
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 
  class( c( ymd("1980-10-14"), NA) )
#[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

This may also explain the other anomalies as well. It may take some tinkering with code that is above my pay grade.

```
> getAnywhere(c.POSIXct)
2 differing objects matching ‘c.POSIXct’ were found
in the following places
  package:base
  registered S3 method for c from namespace base
  namespace:base
  namespace:lubridate
Use [] to view one of them
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because `c(NA,thing)` is not treated like `c(thing,NA)`:

```
> is.POSIXct(c(NA, ymd("1980-01-01")))
[1] FALSE
> is.POSIXct(c(ymd("1980-01-01"),NA))
[1] TRUE
```

In the first case, `base::c` is used because the first argument is `NA`. In the second case, `c.POSIXct` is called because the first argument is `POSIXct`. So in the first case, everything gets reduced down to a numeric vector.

Possible workaround solution is not to construct vectors like that:

```
> c(NA, ymd("1980-10-14")) %--% c(ymd("1981-10-14"), ymd("1982-10-14"))
Error in as.POSIXct.numeric(start) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

but to use `ymd` to construct vectors of the right type by feeding it a vector with the NAs in:

```
> ymd(c(NA, "1980-10-14")) %--% ymd(c("1981-10-14","1982-10-14"))
[1] NA--NA                         1980-10-14 UTC--1982-10-14 UTC
```

Note the code for the `%--%` operator can be seen by typing `interval` - its just an alias for that.

Still odd that `NA %--% ymd()` is NA-NA yet `ymd() %--% NA` has a valid start... Another bug possibly.

Comment: Seems perfectly reasonable the if `c(NA, ymd(.) )` returns a non-POSIXct object that a call to `interval` might also choke when the first argument is NA.

Comment: If you incorporate BondedDust's observation that `class(c(NA, ymd(...)))` is `"numeric"` but `class(c(ymd(...), NA))`is `"POSIXct" "POSIXt"` then I will mark your answer as correct.